# using Clipper library - Angus Johnson => cannot run the code snippet

Tags: polygon, expansion

I'm trying to use Clipper library to expand the obstacle images in my obstacle avoidance robot control assignment. 
But now, I'm even stuck with the example code of the library:

(http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php#code)

## include "clipper.hpp"

```
//from clipper.hpp ...
//typedef signed long long long64;
//struct IntPoint {long64 X; long64 Y;};
//typedef std::vector<IntPoint> Polygon;
//typedef std::vector<Polygon> Polygons;
...
using namespace ClipperLib;

Polygons subj(2), clip(1), solution;

subj[0].push_back(IntPoint(180,200));
subj[0].push_back(IntPoint(260,200));
subj[0].push_back(IntPoint(260,150));
subj[0].push_back(IntPoint(180,150));

subj[1].push_back(IntPoint(215,160));
subj[1].push_back(IntPoint(230,190));
subj[1].push_back(IntPoint(200,190));

clip[0].push_back(IntPoint(190,210));
clip[0].push_back(IntPoint(240,210));
clip[0].push_back(IntPoint(240,130));
clip[0].push_back(IntPoint(190,130));

DrawPolygons(subj, 0x160000FF, 0x600000FF);  // <- identifier not found
DrawPolygons(clip, 0x20FFFF00, 0x30FF0000);  // <- identifier not found

Clipper c;
c.AddPolygons(subject, ptSubject);
c.AddPolygons(clip, ptClip);
if (c.Execute(ctIntersection, solution)
  DrawPolygons(solution, 0x3000FF00, 0xFF006600);
```

I'm wondering if I'm lack of any library installation? I know this is a small question and I'm a bit of a novic but any help can ease a lot of my work. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I'm lack of any library installation?

No, you're not lacking any library. The 'DrawPolygons' function is simply a placeholder for your own code. How you implement the drawing of polygons will depend on the graphics library you intend to use, if any (eg GDI+, OpenGL, Cairo, AGG etc).

(The Clipper package comes with numerous compiled examples that demonstrate how to use Clipper with each of the graphics rendering libraries mentioned above.)

Comment: Just a quick note to Angus - great library!

Comment: Thanks Adi. It's been fun and a real challenge creating it.

Comment: @AngusJohnson From your post regarding Cairo - https://groups.google.com/g/delphionrails/c/8H3GKwnUG4Q - is there a way to use clipper from within Cairo ? So, I have 2 Cairo paths p1 and p2 - how can I use clipper to intersect p1 and p2 ?